# API and logging method creating contacts in database

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

This is API

```
def create_log(self, name, params, response, success, path, model, res_id=None):
    logger_vals = {'name': f'API Call {name}',
                   'type': 'server',
                   'level': 'DEBUG',
                   'path': path,
                   'func': 'TEST',
                   'success_state': success,
                   'res_model': model,
                   'line': f'CALL PARAMS: {params}' if params else 'NO CALL PARAMS',
                   'message': f'RESPONSE: {response}' if response else 'NO RESPONSE'
                   }
    if res_id:
        logger_vals['res_id'] = res_id
    #This line is creating a logging record in database table ir_logging
    self.env['ir.logging'].sudo().create(logger_vals)

@restapi.method([(["/create_contact"], "POST")],
                input_param=restapi.CerberusValidator("_validator_create_contact"), auth="public")
def create_contact(self, **params):
    """Create contact"""
    self._authentication()
    partner_obj = self.env['res.partner'].sudo()
    path = '/create_contact'
    res_model = 'res.partner'
    name = "Create Contact"
    try:
        if params.get('email'):
            #Search is ORM method that selects contanct from res_partner table
            partners = partner_obj.search([('email', '=', params['email'])])
            if partners:
                if any( partner.partner_subtype.is_prepaid for partner in partners):
                    exist_response = {'response': 'Contact already exists'}
                    self.create_log(name, params, exist_response, False, path, res_model)
                    return exist_response

        name = partner_obj._get_sequence_code(code_name='GTIN-13_prepaid', field_name='code')
        partner_type = self.env.ref('contact_cgates.partner_type_individual').id
        sub_type = self.env['res.partner.subtype'].sudo().search([('is_prepaid', '=', True)])
        if not sub_type:
            sub_type_response = {'Error': 'Partner sub type not found'}
            self.create_log(name, params, sub_type_response, False, path, res_model)
            return Response(json.dumps(sub_type_response), status=404)
        #Should I create a separate method for vals and creation?
        partner_vals = {'first_name': params.get('first_name'),
                'last_name': params.get('last_name'),
                'name': name,
                'code': name,
                'partner_type': partner_type,
                'partner_subtype': sub_type.id,
                'city': params.get('city'),
                'email': params.get('email'),
                'mobile': params.get('mobile')}
        #Create is ORM method to INSERT values to res_partner table
        partner = partner_obj.with_context(skip_check=True).create(partner_vals)
        response = {'payers_code': partner.code}
        self.create_log(name, params, response, True, path, res_model, res_id=partner.id)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        self.create_log(name, params, e, False, path, res_model)
        return Response(json.dumps({'Error': f'{e}'}), status=500)
```

I have a few questions here.

1. def `create_log` has too many parameters, how can we deal with that here?
2. in def create_contact `partner_vals` and

   partner = partner_obj.with_context(skip_check=True).create(partner_vals)
   should be in a separate method?
3. Overall I feal this whole thing is kinda messy, so I'm open to any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *def create_log has too many parameters, how can we deal with that here?*

In general, the simplest way of dealing with having too many params is grouping them into structs. Here in your example, path , res_model,name, params are not needed for anything other than logging and yet they are polluting the business function namespace. So what I'd do (pseudocode):

```
    log_ctx = self.create_logger_context(path = '/create_contact', ...)
    ...
    self.create_log(log_ctx, response, True, res_id=partner.id)
```

This new create_log function could either be a wrapper around your more verbose version or you can just change the signature, depending on whether you need a more verbose version in other parts of the code.

2. *In def create_contact partner_vals and
   partner = partner_obj.with_context(skip_check=True).create(partner_vals) should be in a separate method?*

If it has a single responsiblity that you can describe in a couple of words, it should be a method. For example, everything under `params.get('email'):` is a good candidate. If you feel a need to have a comment on a block of the code saying what it is doing(rather than just adding extra information on it), it definitely should be a method.

3. *Overall I feal this whole thing is kinda messy, so I'm open to any suggestions*

- It could use better modularity and abstraction. For instance, I'd prefer a more well-defined interface instead `self.env['res.partner.subtype'].sudo().search([('is_prepaid', '=', True)])` which will make a code more readable and isolate the contact functionality from the details of the sudo stuff which seems like it has nothing to do with.
- I know it is python and all, but I'm really not a fan of using hardcoded strings as the pre-defined dictionary keys. You are one typo away from a bunch of very interesting bugs. Or if you do use hardcoded strings, make sure they are isolated somewhere, like in a create method, rather than sprinkled randomly over contacts.